# Sending interrupt signal to other independent process in C/C++ in linux

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, performance, gcc

I have two programs in C/C++. Program1 has multiple thread (under my control, I can add any code inside this program) and Program2 has one thread(not under my control, so can't add any code). Both programs are running on different CPU core.

Threads in Program1 are running in round-robin fashion.

Is there any way I can control execution of other program2 from program1 by sending any signal or interrupt from thread of Program1?

Is it possible to control execution in the following way ?

```
Step 1 : Thread (i) sends interrupt/notification to start execution of Program2
Step 2 : Program2 start execution
Step 3 : Thread (i+1) sends notification/interrupt to stop execution of Program2 or preempted/scheduled out this process from CPU core.


Core -1 : ---T1----Signal sent to V to start --T2---Signal sent to V to stop--


Core -2 : ---------------- V start here -----------------V stop here------
```

When both Program1 and Program2 are running in same CPU core, I am able to control execution of program2.

```
Core 1 : ----T1----V ----- T2 ----- V -----
```

Now, I want to implement this in a scenario when two independent processes are running in separate CPU core.

I am using gcc/g++ and linux.

Any link to related document/concept or suggestions to implement above idea will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:** We **can't write signal handler code** inside Program2. As it is independent program. We can write anything inside Program1.

**Update 2:** From several comments received so far, it looks like we need to write a signal handler in Program2 to control execution of program2 by using sending signal/interrupt. It is not necessary to send signal/interrupt to control execution (start/pause) of Program2, we can think other way to restrict to run program2, may be by **using cpulimit** or some other way which I don't know.

```
Core -1 : ---T1----Something needs to be done here to start V --T2---Something needs to be done here to stop V--


Core -2 : ---------------- V start here --------------------------------V stop here------
```

Comment: I believe that you can only send signals between processes if they have any kind of relation (i.e father / child). Only the kernel has the ability to send a signal to any process he desires.

Comment: You're looking for Inter Process Communication: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/

Comment: @rafaelcpalmeida That's not true. You can send a signal to any process.

Comment: @rafaelcpalmeida, of course not. You are able to send signals to any process as long as you have perimissions - i.e. is the same user which runs the process or is root.

Comment: @Barmar, not to **any** process.

Comment: @SergeyA my process can send a signal to another process or I (user) can send a signal to another process?

Comment: @rafaelcpalmeida Yes, definitely! Look at the link I posted in my comment above ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, I thought my process could only send signals to his child processes

Comment: The first two paragraphs describe an extremely unlikely OS design.  'Programs' do not run on cores, threads do.

Comment: @terencehill, thanks for commenting and the link you provided. I am just wondering how program2 will react once it get signal/interrupt from program1. Considering both case when Program2 is not under our control and when it is in our control( we can write signal handler code).

Comment: @bholanath Nobody can answer your question because as far as we know program2 is some kind of black box. It's up to YOU to find out about program2 and what mechanisms it *provides* for IPC. Maybe it listens on sockets, maybe it has support for SysV IPC of some form, or maybe it has custom signal handlers for, say, SIGUSR1. Since you say you can't change program2, we can only propose possible mechanisms but we're wasting our time if program2 doesn't support them.

Comment: @kfsone, thank you for your comment. I am trying to control a program execution which is not under my control. May be I need to rephrase the question in a way " how to control execution of a independent program which is running in other core" , may be sending signal is not a solution, may be I need to use some other approach to achieve that.

Comment: There's no general purpose way to do that. The program has to provide some way for it to be controlled. If it's an interactive application that reads input from the terminal, you can use an `Expect` script to control it.

Comment: @Barmar, the other process is running continuously, doing some compute intensive job, so it is not an interactive process which is waiting for some input from terminal. As per Stian's comment I am looking into ptrace option to control (start/stop) execution of other process.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you're looking into `ptrace`, then you can try using a debugger as the interface to it.

Comment: Are you saying you want to control scheduling of program2? To block it from executing for some period of time before allowing it to resume execution?

Comment: @kfsone, you are right. Exactly I am trying to block it for some period of time before allowing it to resume its execution and also allow for very small amount of time so that it can use very little cpu.

Answer (score 3):

You could attach a debugger like `gdb` to the running process. Then you can examine and modify variables, stop the process, force it to call specific functions, etc.

Debuggers make use of the `ptrace` mechanism that was mentioned in comments. This way, you don't need to learn all the details of converting information in the program's symbol table to the actual controlling code, this has all been done by the debugger's author.

You'll need a copy of the program with the symbol table intact for this.

If you just want to suspend the program and resume it, you can do it from the shell:

```
kill -STOP <pid>
kill -CONT <pid>
```

Comment: I need to control execution of other program. How other process will react when it receives interrupt due to kill command ?

Comment: ... and one of the `exec` family to execute a process ([link](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Executing-a-File.html#Executing-a-File))

Comment: @bholanath Use `sigaction` in the receiver to establish a signal handler function.

Comment: @Barmar, I know the pid of running process(cpu intensive process), and in which core it is running, however I don't have access to what you mentioned as - You'll need a copy of the program with the symbol table intact for this. Is there any way to stop this process for a few microsec and again allow it to run for few microsec?

Comment: You just want to stop and start it, not actually make it do specific things?

Comment: @Barmar, I just want to start and stop the other process whenever I want. Actually I just want to restrict another compute intensive process which is running in other CPU core, whose pid I know, I want to interrupt or preempt or schedule out frequently from CPU run queue so that it can't use more cpu. One way I am trying to do this by using cpulimit and nice.

Comment: @Barmar, I have done this in a single cpu when both program1 and program2 are running in same cpu core and program1 allow program2 to run for very small amount of time, before it is preempted by program1.

Comment: @Barmar, I will just try your code using kill -STOP <pid> and kill -CONT <pid> and let you know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pause program2, you can use kill/signal SIGCONT SIGSTOP SIGTSTP.

Since you can not change anything in program2, how would you expect program2 to be able to receive and IPC/remote signals?

Comment: I just want to control the execution of program2 without making any changes in program2. May be sometime program2 will run, sometime it will pause. I was reading about cpulimit , but no idea if it will help to achieve that. Although cpulimit is not related to signal/interrupt.

Comment: you can also use the ptrace API, this allows you to intercept signal receive, making SIGSTOP/SIGCONT invisible, pause at any system call etc.

Comment: does ptrace API needs to include inside Program1 ? If it needs to include Program2 , I can't use that approach. However, I know the pid of Program2. Can I use pid of Program2 inside Program1 using ptrace you are talking about? If yes, a link to related document or a sample code will be a great help.